# Caching viewholders with image into RecyclerView using Glide

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-viewholder

Hello guys I have a problem with RecyclerView
I tried about something like chat.
I have sometimes images and text something only text and something only images in one row in recyclerview.

Everything work good while not scrolling and rows falls out of memory.

when falls out of memory and I want show it again row shown only progressbar, glide not loading.

I use glide into ViewHolder 
I not doing anything other with image in viewholder only code which pasted in this Thread.

```
GlideApp.with(v).load(conv.getUrlFromServer()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(pictureMsg);
```

my viewholders .XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LineLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="left">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/rowCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_Bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_Right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_Top"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/text_End"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/textview_Start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textview_top"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/textview_Right"
                    android:text="Kolo"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
                    card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/pictureMsg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/text_End"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/textview_Start"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:minHeight="0dp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/circleProgresBar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried this

```
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

but unsuccesfull when increase caching number it was logically helped for little scrolling but it's not a solution. and it's use a lot of memory.

it's all what I thing you needed for explain my problem. I Paste Screens for better explain.

this is after launch screen
[image]
Scrolling up for fall of memory.
[image]
and go back on the bottom
[image]
it's permanently loading (glide doing nothing in background)

Sorry for graphics :D

Thanks for any advice.

===================================Added info===============================

Here Is my onBindMethod for me is setDataOnView because have MyGeneriViewholder Implemented

```
@Override
    public void setDataOnView(int position, final RealmModel data) {
        RealmModelMessage conv = (RealmModelMessage) data;
        if (!conv.isStatus()) {
            mRow.setAlpha(0.5f);
        } else {
            mRow.setAlpha(1f);
        }
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llpCard;
        if (conv.getId_from() != mMyId) {
            mText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            mRow.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
         //   mText.setPadding(0, 0, mTextMargin_Right, 0);

            llpCard = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llpCard.setMargins(0, mCardMargin_Top, mCardMargin_Right, mCardMargin_Bottom); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
            mCardView.setLayoutParams(llpCard);
            mCardView.setPadding(mTextMargin_Start, mTextMargin_Top, mTextMargin_End, mTextMargin_Bottom); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
            mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.argb(225,0,238,238));

            if (!String.valueOf(conv.getUrlFromServer()).equals("")){
                pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                GlideApp.with(v).load(conv.getUrlFromServer()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).fitCenter().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  //      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Chyba obrázku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pictureMsg.setBackground(v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(pictureMsg);} else {
                pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        } else {
            mText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            mRow.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            llpCard = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llpCard.setMargins(mCardMargin_Right, mCardMargin_Top, 0, mCardMargin_Bottom); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
            mCardView.setLayoutParams(llpCard);
            mCardView.setPadding(0, mTextMargin_Top, mTextMargin_Start, mTextMargin_Bottom); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
            mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.argb(225,238,238,0));

            if (!String.valueOf(conv.getUrlFromServer()).equals("")){
                circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              //GlideApp.with(v).load(conv.getUrlFromServer()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop().into(pictureMsg);
               GlideApp.with(v).load(conv.getUrlFromServer()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Chyba obrázku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(pictureMsg);

                /*        Drawable drawable=pictureMsg.getDrawable();
                double width =pictureMsg.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
                double heigh =pictureMsg.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
                double widthInScreen= v.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.minWidth_Image150dp);
                double constant= widthInScreen/width;
                double newWidth= width*constant;
                double newHeigh= heigh*constant;
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) newWidth,(int) newHeigh);
                pictureMsg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                */
            } else {
                pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        mText.setText(conv.getText());

}
```

Comment: Can you show the bind viewholder method?

Comment: yes, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem with .override(int)

like this dimen between () is width and heigh.

```
GlideApp.with(v).load(conv.getUrlFromServer()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC).override((int) v.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.minWidth_Image150dp), v.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.minWidth_Image150dp)).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Chyba obrázku", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        pictureMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        circleProgresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(pictureMsg);
```

I don't know what this work good.